# Multiple sql insert happens in DATABASE TABLE

Tags: javascript, php

```
load_post(); // It will execute the function named itself ..in this case no error on inserting record     works normally and fine together with the function

function load_post(){
    $('#load-post-here').html("<div id='post-loader'><img src='./resources/images/loader.gif' /></div>");
    $.post("./php/classroom/load_posts.php",function(data){
        $('#load-post-here').html(data);
            delete_option();
            like(); // Like function here works normally together with comment() function
            comment();
            delete_comment();
    });
}

setInterval(function(){
    check_new_post();
}, 1000);

function check_new_post(){
    $.post("./php/classroom/check_new_post.php",function(data){
        $('#load-post-here').prepend($(data).hide().slideDown(1000));
            delete_option();
            like(); //this where happens the error, it insert multiple records of the same data in auto increment id in record, which is normal to increment, it should be a single record per like hit, the error then was in insert multiple record which is the anomaly
            //comment(); ..together with this comment() function is also inserting multiple records in a single click in same data insert
            //delete_comment();
    });
}

function like(){
    $('a.like-link').on('click',function(){
        var post_id = $(this).attr('post_id');
        var check = $(this).html();
        //alert(check);
        if (check=="Like") {
            $.post("./php/classroom/like.php",{"post_id":post_id},function(response){
                //alert(response);
                $("a.like-link[post_id="+ post_id +"]").html("Unlike");
            });
        }
        if (check=="Unlike") {
            $.post("./php/classroom/unlike.php",{"post_id":post_id},function(response){
                //alert(response);
                $("a.like-link[post_id="+ post_id +"]").html("Like");
            });
        }
    });
```

}

Example is when i hit like button .. When i check my record from database, i see multiple record in a single click.. What i think is, it due to my set interval.. Any suggestion guyz :D

> > NEW i thought it is due to set interval.. what do you think? load_post() works perfectly but check new post() with interval there happens multiple insertion
> >
> > When i change the 1000 to 100 interval.. the more insert happens .. any suggestion

Comment: @StuartLC From the name, I think `check_new_post.php` just checks whether there's anything new and returns it, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: What happens when you hit the like button? What does the like() function do? Show the code.

Comment: Also in your case you better use GET method instead of POST. Because you only need to get information from server about new posts with no data modifications as i suppose

Comment: it may be a copy and paste error but did you properly close the `like()` function? Right now there is a `}` missing

Comment: @dr_dev The code of check_new_post returns all the data from the post table in a set when there a a new record found..and insert the set of data in the load post.. the like() function works seamless when i call on the loaded post for the first time..it works okay. It fails only on the new post inserted.. when i hit like, it insert multiple record ..of the same data

Comment: @RST, yes it is a copy and paste error .. i will edit and explain my codes above

Comment: According to your own findings it is a timing issue. What happens when you set interval to 3000 or higher?.

Comment: @RST , still gets multiple but lesser number...as it increases the set interval, any recommendation? Thank you buddies

Comment: what is in your like.php file?

Comment: @RST , it inserts a row of data when i hit like..to the database.. it works perfectly in load_post() function, with no multiple insert .. multiple insert happens in check_new_post() with interval functions